# how do you assign a value to every word in a list

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, input, split

I'm trying to build a program that searches through a user inputted sentence and then numbers each word depending on its position. If a word appears more then once it will keep its original value.

E.G:

> 'you *ask* my name then ill *ask* yours.' you = 1 ask = 2 my = 3 name = 4 then = 5 ill = 6 ask = 1 yours = 7

So far i have this:

```
Usent = input("write a sentence please: ")
Listsent = Usent.split()
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second instance of `ask` have the value `2`?

Comment: no im trying to make it so if a word appears more then once it keeps its original value

Comment: Yes but in the example you gave, `ask` has the value `2`, but the second instance has the value `1`. If you want to keep the original value, shouldn't the second instance also have the value `2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) with list comprehension:

```
>>> s = "you ask my name then ill ask yours"
>>> [val  + " = "  + str(index) for index, val in enumerate(s.split())]
['you = 0', 'ask = 1', 'my = 2', 'name = 3', 'then = 4', 'ill = 5', 'ask = 6', 'yours = 7']
```

I'll leave the part of handling the "duplicate" indices to you.